# How to fill "holes" in dataset to plot on a table with D3 for zebra striping

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm running into an issue with zebra striping my table when there is "missing" data. I'll explain below with an abstracted example:

Say I have painting objects. Each painting has an artist and belongs to a set.

```
[{
    'name':'The Jewish Bride',
    'set':3,
    'artist':'Rembrandt'
 },...]
```

---

##### Approach 0

It's pretty straightforward to get a table going where each artist is displayed with the names of their paintings.

| Artist | Painting |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rembrandt | The Jewish Bride | Another painting name | … |
| Another artist | … |  |  |
| … | … |  |  |

Here's a sample codepen:
https://codepen.io/KevinGutowski/pen/gOobaeR

---

#### Approach 1

The difficulty comes in where I'm trying to group these paintings by set. Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish

| Artist | Set 1 | Set 2 | Set 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Leonardo da Vinci | Mona Lisa (1) |  | Last Supper (3) |
| Michelangelo |  | The Creation of Adam (2) |  |
| Rembrandt | The Night Watch (1), Herman Doomer (1) |  | The Jewish Bride (3) |

My 'missing" data stems from the fact that some artists don't have a painting in a set.

I tried using a `<table>` to plot this data out but couldn't figure out how to properly position the cells in the correct columns:

| Artist | Set 1 | Set 2 | Set 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Leonardo da Vinci | Mona Lisa (1) | Last Supper (3) |  |
| Michelangelo | The Creation of Adam (2) |  |  |
| Rembrandt | The Night Watch (1), Herman Doomer (1) | The Jewish Bride (3) |  |

https://codepen.io/KevinGutowski/pen/RwxNWyK

The empty data causes all the cells to shift over to the left.

---

#### Approach 2

Finally, in attempt to fix the position issue I converted over to using css `grid`.

https://codepen.io/KevinGutowski/pen/VwywoxX

I get really close however now that I want to zebra stripe my rows, it's impossible due to the empty "cells" in my grid.

---

Any ideas for how to approach this? Regardless if I'm using a `<table>` or css `grid` it seems like I need to setup my data so that each row has some object (even if its empty) within each column.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering tabular data in `d3` is probably one of the few cases, where it is better to have wide data instead of long data.

In order to get your data from long into wide the `d3.group` is a first step (although I liked the deprecated `d3.nest` more, because it kept the original keys) and then flatten the nested structure. Something like this works for your use case:

```
const paintingsByArtistAndSet = Array.from(
  d3.group(paintings,d => d.artist, d => d.set),
  ([artist, sets]) => {
    let ret = {};
    ret["Artist"] = artist;
    Array.from(sets).forEach(d => {
      ret["Set " + d[0]] = d[1].map(d => d.name).join(", ");
    });
    return ret;
  }
 );
```

Whenever you have wide data, you can easily generate an array of columns using a `set`, even if not every row has an entry for every column:

```
const columns = Array.from(data.reduce((cols, d) => {
    Object.keys(d).forEach(col => {
    cols.add(col);
  });
  return cols;
}, new Set()));
```

Then, use this `columns` array as data for appending the table cells in each row.

```
rows.selectAll("td")    
  .data(row => columns.map(col => col in row ? row[col] : "-"))
  .join("td")
```

```js
const paintings = [{
    'name': 'Mona Lisa',
    'set': 1,
    'artist': 'Leonardo da Vinci'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Last Supper',
    'set': 2,
    'artist': 'Leonardo da Vinci'
  },
  {
    'name': 'The Creation of Adam',
    'set': 2,
    'artist': 'Michelangelo'
  },
  {
    'name': 'The Night Watch',
    'set': 1,
    'artist': 'Rembrandt'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Herman Doomer',
    'set': 1,
    'artist': 'Rembrandt'
  },
  {
    'name': 'The Jewish Bride',
    'set': 3,
    'artist': 'Rembrandt'
  }
];

const paintingsByArtistAndSet = Array.from(
  d3.group(paintings, d => d.artist, d => d.set),
  ([artist, sets]) => {
    let ret = {};
    ret["Artist"] = artist;
    Array.from(sets).forEach(d => {
      ret["Set " + d[0]] = d[1].map(d => d.name).join(", ");
    });
    return ret;
  }
);

const columns = Array.from(paintingsByArtistAndSet.reduce((cols, d) => {
  Object.keys(d).forEach(col => {
    cols.add(col);
  });
  return cols;
}, new Set()));

const table = d3.select("body").append("table");

table.append("thead")
  .append("tr")
  .selectAll("th")
  .data(columns)
  .join("th")
  .text(d => d);

table.append("tbody")
  .selectAll("tr")
  .data(paintingsByArtistAndSet)
  .join("tr")
  .selectAll("td")
  .data(row => columns.map(col => col in row ? row[col] : "-"))
  .join("td")
  .text(d => d);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the example and the explanation. This all helps a ton!